# React useEffect hook and eslint warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I’m looking for recommendations about how to solve the following problem:

I have a component A that has two states, state1 and state2.

If I want to run an effect only when state1 changes but in the useEFfect callback I use the value of state2, how can I solve the issue about array dependencies eslint react hooks warning ?

Ex.

```
function A() {
    const [state1, setState1] = useState(0);
    const [state2, setState2] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const a = state1 + state2;
        // do some async logic using a
 
    }, [state1]); //Here eslint react hooks rule requests adding state2 to the dependency array!

return <div> some text </div>

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The common method would typically be to disable the linting rule specifically for that line.

```
function A() {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState(0);
  const [state2, setState2] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // do some async logic using a
    const a = state1 + state2;

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [state1]);

  return <div> some text </div>;
}
```

But the drawback here is it can mask dependency issues if the dependencies ***actually*** change and you forget to update the dependency array.

You can use a React ref and an additional `useEffect` hook to cache a current `state2` value and refer to this in the other `useEffect` callback.

```
function A() {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState(0);
  const [state2, setState2] = useState(0);

  const state2Ref = useRef(state2);

  useEffect(() => {
    state2Ref.current = state2;
  }, [state2]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // do some async logic using a
    const a = state1 + state2Ref.current;
  }, [state1]);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

```js
function A() {
  const [state1, setState1] = React.useState(0);
  const [state2, setState2] = React.useState(0);

  const state2Ref = React.useRef(state2);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    state2Ref.current = state2;
  }, [state2]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // do some async logic using a
    const a = state1 + state2Ref.current;
    console.log("effect called", a);
  }, [state1]);

  return (
    <div>
      some text
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setState1((c) => c + 1)}>
          Update State 1
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setState2((c) => c + 1)}>
          Update State 2
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <A />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` to your userEffect like this:

```
function A() {
    const [state1, setState1] = useState(0);
    const [state2, setState2] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const a = state1 + state2;
        // do some async logic using a


       // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [state1]); //Here eslint react hooks rule requests adding state2 to the dependency array!

    return <div> some text </div>

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Luccin but I’m looking for a more advanced way without disabling this rule. For example I thought about creating a new ref that holds the updated value of state2...